# Why are rails assets broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm running a rails app with passenger on my personal server (running debian) and i seem to have an issue with assets. First it was some images that were broken that i put in app/assets/images/slideshow. I was able to get these images to render by running "rake assets:precompile" and that fixed the images, but this also killed the glyphicons from the bootstrap slideshow i'm using.

How should i be handling this process? should i be doing precompile at all? it seems somewhere i'm missing something in the process.

Right now the glyphicons want to point to /assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff but the icon is actually at assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-cf24e42fad297dbaa33853187ba876e7.woff

Comment: Looks like your assets are precompiled in a production environment (ie. with assets digesting) but you're running the app in a different one.

Comment: i added to my apache conf RailsEnv production but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Can you tell whether the app is running in the right env?

Comment: i solved this by running RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually. it seems that i solved this in production by running

```
    RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I'd still like some clarification of assets if someone feels like it

Comment: Yes, you have to precompile for your production set up each time.

Comment: Why the bundle exec needed?

Comment: it insures that the command uses the environment of that directory instead of global.